# Excel 2010: "Too Many Different Cell Formats" error when no cells are formatted

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm getting the "Too Many Different Cell Formats" error whenever I try to format a cell. The weird thing is, there are no formatted cells in the workbook. I confirmed this by going through each tab and hitting Select All -> Clear Formats.

Does anyone know what could cause this?